# Long click on screen in android

Tags: android

How should I implement long click on the screen in android?

After long click by the user I should specify some options to trigger.

And I have used scrollview under that I have used tableview.

How can i do this ?

scenario is as follows:
after clicking on contact name in the mobile,it navigates us to contact details,and there i need to use long press on the screen

Comment: For which you want to implement long click event method?

Comment: So... A long press listener. For a button or what?

Comment: on clicking on screen i want..

Comment: after clicking on contact name in the mobile,it navigates us to contact details,and there i need to use long press on the screen.